# Router needs restart every half an hour for the internet to work

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, fiber

I'm using a local fibre boardband which comes to a generic GPON unit (is it called GPON ONU?) provided by the ISP and from there goes to my router (Dlink Covr 1100). Now for the last few days, all the devices (wired and wireless) get suddenly disconnected from the internet and wifi and only come back when I restart the router. Some times it doesn't disconnect right away but fails to load any page and then disconnects after few attempts. Then after sometimes it reconnects itself to wifi and internet but doesn't load any page. All the status LEDs on both the ONU and router are OK during this whole thing. I first thought it's the ISP, but I realized the net works after a router restart. The ONU didn't seem to play any part in this. The router is 6 to 8 months old. The weather also has been bad a couple of days but it has been worse previously. So I don't understand what exactly the problem here. I tried reseting the router but nothing changed. Firmware is current. Any idea or suggestions?

I'm also willing to invest in a costlier router if that's what it takes, but not sure how different the performance will be.

By the way the generic ONU looks like this
https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1qk8JXifrK1RjSspbq6A4pFXap/Fiber-optic-RJ45-epon-onu-ONT-EP-125-FTTH-EPON-Onu-EPON-1port-ONU-EPON-OLT.jpg

Comment: I have seen similar behavior due to a minor dip in lines voltage.  A small "brownout" is an issue for the router and the  GPON ONU.  The power dip is often small and with fluorescent lights in many offices it goes unnoticed. Everything looks fine ( lights all normal)  but a reset is needed to correct the issue.  A small UPS solved the problem for a number of clients experiencing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

By your description, it seems that the problem is with the router.
I suggest to contact the ISP Support.

The router's
[manual](https://cdatatec.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/FD212H-1FE1GE1POTS-EPON-ONU-User-Manual_V1.1.pdf)(?)
has a RESET button, probably intended for introducing the end of a paper-clip,
which will do a factory reset. Support will know if it will still work
afterward.

You may also ask about a firmware update to the router.

In the worst case, ask for the router to be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

First you can shut down and reset the [ONU](https://www.bt-pon.com/product/1ge-xpon-onu-bt-122xr), observe for a period of time, if this problem still occurs, consider if it is a heat dissipation problem, check if the ONU or router is running too hot, if the above methods ultimately do not solve the problem, consider replacing the ONU or router, such as TP-LINK.

Comment: I tried connecting the onu directly to my pc without router, and it worked. The router only works after frequent restart. I now remember my previous router had this same problem. Is it a heat problem or the router’s small memory problem?